# Programmatically add IP to Server 2008 firewall rule

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall

Anybody know how to programmatically add an IP address to a Server 2008 Windows Firewall with Advanced Security rule?

i.e. I've setup a Block Action firewall rule which has some IP addresses listed under the "Remote IP address" section of the Scope. I want to be able to programmatically add (or perhaps remove) IP addresses from this list. Are there .NET objects available to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Start Page can be found at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff956124(v=VS.85).aspx

Specifically, it seems you need the INetFwRule Interface which is described at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365344(v=VS.85).aspx

Check the get_RemoteAddresses and put_RemoteAddresses

Answer (score 8):

You can also try the [netsh](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242468) environment.
I used it once for changing the MTU of my interface

Answer (score 8):

I just made this work in vb.NET.
Add a refrence to "c:\windows\system32\firewallapi.dll"

Make a class called Firewall - like so:

```
Imports NetFwTypeLib
Imports System.Net

Public Class Firewall
    Implements IDisposable
    Private _policy As INetFwPolicy2 = Nothing

    Private ReadOnly Property Policy As INetFwPolicy2
        Get
            If _policy Is Nothing Then
                _policy = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")), INetFwPolicy2)
            End If
            Return _policy
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Add(ipAddress As IPAddress, ruleName As String)
        Dim firewallRule As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule = Policy.Rules.Item(ruleName)
        Dim NewAddress As String = ipAddress.ToString & "/255.255.255.255"
        If Not firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress) Then
            firewallRule.RemoteAddresses += "," & NewAddress
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Remove(ipAddress As IPAddress, ruleName As String)
        Dim firewallRule As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule = Policy.Rules.Item(ruleName)
        Dim NewAddress As String = ipAddress.ToString & "/255.255.255.255"
        If firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress) Then
            Dim ipList As String = firewallRule.RemoteAddresses
            ipList = ipList.Replace(NewAddress, "")
            ipList = ipList.Replace(",,", ",")
            firewallRule.RemoteAddresses = ipList
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function Exists(ipAddress As IPAddress, ruleName As String) As Boolean
        Dim firewallRule As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule = Policy.Rules.Item(ruleName)
        Dim NewAddress As String = ipAddress.ToString & "/255.255.255.255"
        If firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Private disposedValue As Boolean
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
            End If
            If Not _policy Is Nothing Then
                _policy = Nothing
            End If
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 6):

I think that the information you're looking for is available here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx

Comment: Archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20100612155926/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @NoOne's Answer in case someone wants to deal with ipv6 addresses too this worked for me

```
Imports NetFwTypeLib
Imports System.Net

Public Class Firewall
    Implements IDisposable
    Private _policy As INetFwPolicy2 = Nothing

    Private ReadOnly Property Policy As INetFwPolicy2
        Get
            If _policy Is Nothing Then
                _policy = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")), INetFwPolicy2)
            End If
            Return _policy
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Add(ipAddress As IPAddress, ruleName As String)
        Dim firewallRule As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule = Policy.Rules.Item(ruleName)       
        Dim NewAddress As String
        If IpClass(ipAddress).Equals("ipv4") Then
            NewAddress = ipAddress.ToString & "/255.255.255.255"
        Else
            NewAddress = ipAddress.ToString & "/128"
        End If


        If Not firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress) Then
            firewallRule.RemoteAddresses += "," & NewAddress
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Remove(ipAddress As IPAddress, ruleName As String)
        Dim firewallRule As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule = Policy.Rules.Item(ruleName)
        Dim NewAddress As String
        If IpClass(ipAddress).Equals("ipv4") Then
            NewAddress = ipAddress.ToString & "/255.255.255.255"
        Else
            NewAddress = ipAddress.ToString & "/128"
        End If
        If firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress) Then
            Dim ipList As String = firewallRule.RemoteAddresses
            ipList = ipList.Replace(NewAddress, "")
            ipList = ipList.Replace(",,", ",")
            firewallRule.RemoteAddresses = ipList
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function Exists(ipAddress As IPAddress, ruleName As String) As Boolean
        Dim firewallRule As NetFwTypeLib.INetFwRule = Policy.Rules.Item(ruleName)
        Dim NewAddress4 As String = ipAddress.ToString & "/255.255.255.255"
        Dim NewAddress6 As String = ipAddress.ToString & "/128"
        If firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress4) Or firewallRule.RemoteAddresses.Contains(NewAddress6) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

   Public Function IpClass(ipAddress As String) As String
        If ipAddress.Contains(".") Then
            Return "ipv4"
        Else
            Return "ipv6"
        End If
    End Function

    Private disposedValue As Boolean
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
            End If
            If Not _policy Is Nothing Then
                _policy = Nothing
            End If
        End If
        Me.disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```