# Looking for good solutions for blocking TOR

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, tor

I am running an asp.net mvc website, and i want to block every user that reaches my site through TOR. By now i have two solutions:

1. Download list of TOR exit nodes once every hour, store that list in
   memory, and check every request IP address with that list.
2. Try to block TOR exit nodes with windows firewall - i think that this would
   be better, but i don't know how to do that.

Is there any other possible solution? Have any of you maybe had a similar problem to mine? How did you solve it?

Comment: Why would you block TOR?

Comment: I would go with #1. Curious, why do you want to block TOR?

Comment: Because i have very sensitive data on my website, and blocking tor is just another way of protecting it.

Comment: @ojek That doesn't make much sense. How do you protect data if you just blacklist a few IPs?

Comment: By doing so, i am sure that even if somone hacks my website, there will be bigger chance of tracking them up. TOR makes hackers almost 100% invulnerable.

Comment: Although I respect your intentions, unfortunately I think blocking TOR will be a futile exercise for many reasons. I'd concentrate your efforts on other forms of security. Good place to start is the OWASP project: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: And what about if legitimate TOR users wants to visit your web site? TOR may be used for malicious usages it's true, but can also be a way of thinking for some people, eager to preserve their anonymity. Or even for users from countries with censorship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is absolutely the second option you listed. You will have to download a list of known exit node IP's every so often regardless of which solution you use, but using the firewall that already exists is much more simple than rolling your own primitive replica.

How the IP's can be added to the firewall depends on your version of Windows. A previous StackOverflow question whose answer includes links that explain how to programmatically block IP addresses via the Windows Server 2008 firewall can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382933/programmatically-add-ip-to-server-2008-firewall-rule).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/RD17/DeTor)(https://github.com/RD17/DeTor) is a simple REST API which use [TorDNSEl](https://www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en) to determine whether a request was made from TOR network or not. I think it will be pretty simple to use it from C# with RESTSharp for example.

The request is:
`curl -X GET http://detor.ambar.cloud/`.

The response is 

`{ 
  "sourceIp": "104.200.20.46",
  "destIp": "89.207.89.82",
  "destPort": "8080",
  "found": true 
}`

As a bonus you can add a badge to your site to detect whether a user comes from TOR or not:

`<img src='http://detor.ambar.cloud/badge' />`