# C# Netfwtypelib - add more than 1 remote address?

Tags: c#, firewall

How to add more than 1 ip address to firewall rule with C#?

I tried to do things like:

```
rule.RemoteAddresses += "127.0.0.1";
rule.RemoteAddresses += "129.0.0.1";
```

or

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("127.0.0.1");
list.Add("129.0.0.1");
rule.RemoteAddresses = list.ToString();
```

but it will give you only exception.

Comment: "but it will give you only exception." - that exception and corresponding stack trace should be added to your question.

Comment: `list.ToString();` returns `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`. That's not how you convert a list to a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found it on [Programmatically add IP to Server 2008 firewall rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382933/programmatically-add-ip-to-server-2008-firewall-rule)

Working code:

```
INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
var rule = firewallPolicy.Rules.Item("Block Bad IP Addresses");

rule.RemoteAddresses += "," + ip;
```

Comment: So in other words it's a comma-separated list.